# Need help in packaging app using TideSDK on Windows

Tags: tidesdk

I developed an application using TideSDK on windows and when I click `LaunchApp` it works fine. Now I moved to package it and installed ImageMagick and Wix 3.0 as required for packaging on Windows. Then I clicked on `Package with runtime` and then I cannot guess where the packaged app is? I found a file 'installer' in the workspace but when I click on it it says `installer could not find the application path`. I think the application is not being packaged properly.

Here is the log that I see in TideSDK:

```
  Preparing to package desktop app together with runtime. One moment...
Staging Trial
-> Copying contents from D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial to D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial
-> Copying installer from C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\installer to D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial
-> Copying runtime to D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\app\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\codec\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\database\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\filesystem\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\media\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\monkey\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\network\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\platform\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\process\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\ui\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\worker\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\modules\php\1.3.1-beta
-> Copying tiboot.exe to D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-8 2013-08-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lzma openexr pango png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
-> Launching: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\ReplaceVistaIcon.exe "D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\Trial.exe" "D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial\Resources\_converted_icon.ico"
->
Language="1033" Codepage="1252"
UpgradeCode="a83b9953-f973-4ed6-8c94-8c5e997374b1">
Description="Trial"
Comments="None provided" Manufacturer="None provided"
InstallerVersion="300" Languages="1033" Compressed="yes" SummaryCodepage="1252" />
Minimum='0.0.1' IncludeMinimum='yes'
Maximum="1.0.0" IncludeMaximum='yes' />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
-> Launching: ['C:\\Program Files\\Windows Installer XML v3\\bin\\candle.exe', '-out', 'D:\\LAB\\TideSDK\\Trial\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs.wixobj', 'D:\\LAB\\TideSDK\\Trial\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs']
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 3.0.5419.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
installer.wxs
-> Launching: ['C:\\Program Files\\Windows Installer XML v3\\bin\\light.exe', '-ext', ' WixUIExtension', '-out', u'D:\\LAB\\TideSDK\\Trial\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\Trial.msi', 'D:\\LAB\\TideSDK\\Trial\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs.wixobj']
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Linker version 3.0.5419.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.100.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.101.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.103.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.104.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.193.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.238.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.100.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.101.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.103.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.104.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.193.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.238.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE25: Possible dependency failure as we do not find CRT.Policy.63E949F6_03BC_5C40_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E@0 v in ModuleSignature table
D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\installer.wxs(464) : warning LGHT1076 : ICE60: The file _85_file is not a Font, and its version is not a companion file reference. It should have a language specified in the Language column.
D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\installer.wxs(15) : warning LGHT1076 : ICE61: This product should remove only older versions of itself. The Maximum version is not less than the current product. (1.0.0 1.0.0)
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdminExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdminUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdvtExecuteSequence
Done packaging!
```

I think it may also be the case that the app is packaged properly and I am not finding the right package. What file/folder do you use as a distribution package after packaging?

Comment: Does `D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial.msi` exist?

Comment: @Maria:Thanks .It exists and working fine.Actually I was looking in another folder with installer in it.Please post it as an answer and get your bounty.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK currently supports `bundled` installation only, i.e. Package With Runtime Option within TideSDK Developer. You can also use commandline tool `tidebuilder.py`. The usage of the tool is documented: [here](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Packaging-TideSDK-apps)

The generated installer is created inside packages folder.

You should be able to distribute the bundled msi installer for your application.

Exact path particular to your current application:

`D:\LAB\TideSDK\Trial\packages\win32\bundle\Trial.msi`